sveltekit Load function isn't being rerun when I navigate to the same url with different id parameter
Load function isn't being rerun when I navigate to the same url with different id parameter
my folder is like this

+page.server.ts
import api from '$lib/api'
import { getServer } from '$lib/getServer'

export const load = async (event: any) => {
    const token = event.locals.token
    try {
        const [product, products] = await Promise.all([
            getServer(api.getProduct + event.params.id, token),
            getServer(api.getProducts, token),
        ])
        return {
            product: product,
            products: products,
        }
    } catch (error) {
        return { product: [], products: [] }
    }
}

+page.svelte , url of this route is like this http://localhost:1144/products/doctor-phone
<script lang="ts">
    import { siteUrl } from '$lib/config'
    import type { ProductData } from '$lib/interface'
    import urls from '$lib/urls'
    export let data: any
    let product: ProductData = data.product
    let products: ProductData[] = data.products
</script>

<div class="pb-16 sm:pb-24 lg:pt-6">
    <div>{product.title}</div>
    {#each products as item}
        <a href={siteUrl + urls.products + item.identifier}>
            some product 1
        </a>
    {/each}
</div>
// the link hrefs look like this http://localhost:1144/products/camera-nest-2024

when I click the link(anchor tag), the browser address bar did change to the whatever url I clicked, but the load function doesn't run/rerun. therefore no new data loaded.
Why is it ?
